# All numbers close enough to 1 are squares

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Behind this provocative title is a precise question. I have been working on some books and papers claiming the following.

Let $F$ be a number field, and denote by $p$ its finite places. Here is the claim I would like to understand:

> For all place $p$ above 2, there is $n_p$ sufficiently large so that for all $x \in F_p$, if $\mathrm{ord}_p(a-1) \geqslant n_p$ implies $x \in F_p^2$.

That means that for even places, there are neighbourhood of 1 made only of squares. Why is that true? If I think of the rational dyadics $\mathbb{Q}_2$, that would mean with usual notations 
$$x = 1 + \sum_{n \geqslant n_p} a_n 2^n,$$

but I am far from seing a square here. What am I missing? And how can I adapt this to more general number fields?

Comment: I didn't know what a "place" is, so here is a link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201512/place-vs-prime-in-a-number-field also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Places

Answer (score 6):

Over $\Bbb Q_2$, the neighbourhood $1+8\Bbb Z_2$ of $1$ is made up of
squares. An argument using Hensel's lemma proves that $x^2=a$ is soluble
over $\Bbb Z_2$ whenever $a\equiv1\pmod8$ in $\Bbb Z_2$.

The same is true in any finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$. It's fairly obvious
when $p$ is odd, but one has to use a stronger form on Hensel when $p=2$.

Alternatively it drops out from the theory of the $p$-adic exponential
and logarithm. (They are continuous bijections near the identity.)

Comment: Hensel's lemma seems to be the key then, but what about odd cases? Is that obvious that all (?) numbers are squares in the p-adics?

Comment: I understand that Hensel's lemma can be used in order to lift a quadratic residue modulo p to a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$: if $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then the polynomial $x^2-a$ has a root mod $p$ and Hensel's lemma applies to lift it to a root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. However, this requires to begin with a quadratic residue. My question turns therefore to be: why are all the elements close enough to one quadratic residues?

Comment: $1$ is a quadratic residue: every element in $\Bbb Q_p$ close enough to $1$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$. @TheStudent

Comment: Is that also obvious for extensions, i.e. for more general number fields? How do I determine precisely this neighbourhood? For instance for a prime ideal above 2?

Comment: As I said, you can use the $p$-adic logarithm and exponential. Also the version of Hensel that says that if $|f(a)|<|f'(a)|^2$ then $a$ lifts to a solution of $f(x)=0$